# When would getters and setters with mutex be thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Consider the following class:

```
class testThreads
{
private:
    int var; // variable to be modified
    std::mutex mtx; // mutex
public:
    void set_var(int arg) // setter
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
        var = arg;
    }

    int get_var() // getter
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
        return var;
    }

    void hundred_adder()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int got = get_var();
            set_var(got + 1);
            sleep(0.1);
        }
     }
};
```

When I create two threads in main(), each with a thread function of `hundred_adder` modifying the same variable var, the end result of the var is always different i.e. not 200 but some other number.

Conceptually speaking, why is this use of mutex with getter and setter functions not thread-safe? Do the lock-guards fail to prevent the race-condition to var? And what would be an alternative solution?

Comment: A - get, B - get, A - set, B - set. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Thread a: get 0
Thread b: get 0
Thread a: set 1
Thread b: set 1
```

Lo and behold, var is 1 even though it should've been 2.

It should be obvious that you need to lock the whole operation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
     var += 1;
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the variable atomic (even a relaxed one could do in your case).

Answer (score 3):

```
  int got = get_var();
  set_var(got + 1);
```

Your `get_var()` and `set_var()` themselves are thread safe. But this combined sequence of `get_var()` followed by `set_var()` is not. There is no mutex that protects this entire sequence.

You have multiple concurrent threads executing this. You have multiple threads calling `get_var()`. After the first one finishes it and unlocks the mutex, another thread can lock the mutex immediately and obtain the same value for `got` that the first thread did. There's absolutely nothing that prevents multiple threads from locking and obtaining the same `got`, concurrently.

Then both threads will call `set_var()`, updating the mutex-protected `int` to the same value.

That's just one possibility that can happen here. You could easily have multiple threads acquiring the mutex sequentially and thus incrementing `var` by several values, only to be followed by some other, stalled thread, that called `get_var()` several seconds ago, and only now getting around to calling `set_var()`, thus resetting `var` to a much smaller value.

Comment: ...Which is why thread safety is not _composable_.  I.e., Building a program/library/class/whatever entirely out of thread-safe parts does not make the whole thing thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The code show in thread-safe in a sense that it will never set or get partial value of the variable.

But your usage of the methods does not guarantee that value will correctly change: reading and writing from multiple threads can collide with each other. Both threads read the value (11), both increment it (to 12) and than both set to the same (12) - now you counted 2 but effectively incremented only once.

Option to fix:

- provide "safe increment" operation
- provide equivalent of [InterlockedCompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx) to make sure value you are updating correspond to original one and retry as necessary
- wrap calling code into separate mutex or use other synchronization mechanism to prevent operations to intermix.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use std::atomic for the shared data (var in this case)? That will be more safe efficient.

Comment: ... perhaps, but then he would never know the answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an absolute classic.
One thread obtains the value of `var`, releases the `mutex` and another obtains the same value before the first thread has chance to update it.

Consequently the process risks losing increments.

There are three obvious solutions:

```
void testThreads::inc_var(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    ++var;
}
```

That's safe because the mutex is held until the variable is updated.

Next up:

```
bool testThreads::compare_and_inc_var(int val){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    if(var!=val) return false;
    ++var;
    return true;
}

Then write code like:

   int val;
   do{
       val=get_var();
   }while(!compare_and_inc_var(val));
```

This works because the loop repeats until it confirms it's updating the value it read. This could result in live-lock though in this case it has to be transient because a thread can only fail to make progress because another does.

Finally replace `int var` with `std::atomic<int> var` and either use `++var` or `var.compare_exchange(val,val+1)` or `var.fetch_add(1);` to update it.
NB: Notice `compare_exchange(var,var+1)` is invalid...

`++` is guaranteed to be atomic on `std::atomic<>` types but despite 'looking' like a single operation in general no such guarantee exists for `int`.

`std::atomic<>` also provides appropriate memory barriers (and ways to hint what kind of barrier is needed) to ensure proper inter-thread communication.

`std::atomic<>` should be a wait-free, lock-free implementation where available. Check your documentation and the flag `is_lock_free()`.